# Trouble locating binary from heroku buildpack

Tags: git, heroku, buildpack

I'm unable to locate a binary installed using a heroku buildpack.

I add the buildpack to my app using

```
heroku buildpack:add <url>
git commit -m "message"
git push heroku master
```

I can see the buildpack has been added to the app when I execute `heroku buildpacks`.

This should put the binary in `/app/bin`. Yet I'm unable to reference the binary in my code. Additionally, I'm unable to see the binary when I run:

```
heroku run bash
$ ls /bin
```

I've been unsuccessful with several similar buildpacks, so the problem is me, not the buildpack.

Specifically, [this](https://elements.heroku.com/buildpacks/khaitu/heroku-buildpack-wkhtmltopdf#buildpack-instructions) is the buildpack I'm trying to use.

Comment: (a) `/app/bin` ≠ `/bin`. (b) Are you using the `heroku-18` stack, which that buildpack explicitly says isn't tested?

Comment: (a) The binary is in neither ```/app/bin``` nor ```/bin```. (b) I've tried deploying on ```heroku-16``` and ```heroku-18```.

Comment: Update: I resolved the issue using a Heroku Deploy button